# Connection string to connect sql server 2008 which is in another server

Tags: sql-server-2008, vbscript, asp-classic, connection-string

I use the below connection string to connect to a sqlserver 2008 located in another server.
How to i connect to it from ASP using vbscript?

```
application("database_connectionstring_internal") = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=53.90.111.22;DATABASE=crm_cos;UID=cos_user;PASSWORD=1q2w3e4r5t"
```

Here are my server details :

Database server :
Server IP - 53.90.111.22

Sql server name - SCD13B

User name - cos_user

password - 1q2w3e4r5t

Database name - crm_user

Comment: How do you connect to it **using which technology**?  .Net, C++, Java, etc.?

Comment: Please, tell me your password is not really the one you wrote... do not publish passwords!!!

Comment: @Will A, i am using asp with vbscript

Comment: @Macra, Yeah i know. None of the info is real

Comment: @Anuya, @Macra - I can vouch for the information not being real - I tried to connect and got into the CIAs mainframe.  What a disappointment.  :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using something like this:

**C#**

```
"Data Source=host's ip\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=yourddbb;User ID=youruser;Password=yourpassword"
```

**ASP 3.0**

```
StrConex= ""
StrConex= StrConex & "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=yourpasswd;"
StrConex= StrConex & "Persist Security Info=True;User ID=youruser;"
StrConex= StrConex & "Initial Catalog=yourddbb;Data Source=host's ip\SQLEXPRESS"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try --

```
Dim oConn
Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=53.90.111.22;Database=crm_user;Uid=cos_user;Pwd=1q2w3e4r5t"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities :

1 - Add connection string to your web.config as show in this post :  ["Using connection strings from web.config in ASP.NET v2.0"](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/08/26/Using-connection-strings-from-web.config-in-ASP.NET-v2.0.aspx)

2 -Add the connection to code-behind :

```
 Dim strConnect As String=”Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=SSPI;” 

 Dim myConnection As SqlConnection=New SqlConnection(strConnect)

 MyConnection.Open()
```

Comment: Which doesn't help since the OP isn't using .net